# How do I save multiple forms in the same Django View from the same Model? Currently the last form overwrites in save

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How do I save multiple forms in the same Django View from the same Model?

Currently the last form overwrites in save

**views.py**

```
def createrequest_1(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':

    form1 = SurveyNameForm(request.POST)
    form2 = Question1Form(request.POST)
    form3 = Question2Form(request.POST)

    if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form3.is_valid():
        survey = form1.save(commit=False)
        question1 = form2.save(commit=False)
        question2 = form3.save(commit=False)
        survey.survey_creation_date = datetime.date.today()
        survey.customuser = request.user
        survey.save() 
        question1.survey = survey 
        question1.save()
        question2.survey = survey 
        question2.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('createrequest_2')
    else:
        form = SurveyNameForm()

  return render(request, 'requestapp/createrequest_1.html', {'SurveyNameForm': SurveyNameForm, 'Question1Form':Question1Form, 'Question2Form': Question2Form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set different prefix for every form. 
Put instances of forms for render in the template.

In this way:

```
def createrequest_1(request):
    form1 = SurveyNameForm(request.POST or None, prefix='survey')
    form2 = Question1Form(request.POST or None, prefix='question1')
    form3 = Question2Form(request.POST or None, prefix='question2')

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form3.is_valid():
            survey = form1.save(commit=False)
            question1 = form2.save(commit=False)
            question2 = form3.save(commit=False)
            survey.survey_creation_date = datetime.date.today()
            survey.customuser = request.user
            survey.save()
            question1.survey = survey
            question1.save()
            question2.survey = survey
            question2.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('createrequest_2')


    return render(request, 'requestapp/createrequest_1.html',
                  {'SurveyNameForm': form1, 'Question1Form': form2, 'Question2Form': form3})
```

This is explained in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.prefix

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my issue!! Do you know how to remove the 'this field is required' message from the display output?  Using your code has added this in but i'm not sure what is creating it.

Comment: Instance forms in this way for remove required message: form1 = SurveyNameForm(request.POST or None, prefix='survey')
    form2 = Question1Form(request.POST or None, prefix='question1')
    form3 = Question2Form(request.POST  or None, prefix='question2')